# How did Sasuke survive the Tsuchikage's particle style?

Tags: naruto

In the battle between Sasuke and the 5 kages at one point Onoki uses his particle style on Sasuke and Karin notes that his chakra has been completely eliminated, but then somehow Obito brings Sasuke back from his sharingan dimension and then suddenly he is alive again.

Has there ever been an explanation as to how Obito saved Sasuke here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've answered this one yourself - Obito intervened and teleported Sasuke to the Kamui dimension, thus preventing his death.

Comment: I think his question is more like, "We didn't see Obito inside the square of Tsuchikage's particle style. How did Obito get there, touch Sasuke, teleported both of them away in that split second?" We've seen in multiple occasion that it tooks some time for Obito to teleport someone of something.

Comment: @Albert what you are saying is true, but Minato himself admitted that Obito was fast during 9 tails attack on Konoha, yet it was unclear how fast his kamui is. Maybe he was somehow able to teleport Sasuke to his Kamui dimension before Ohnoki's particle jutsu became effective.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I would want to clear is that Obito can prepare for the Kamui before actually casting it.Kamui is not a quick jutsu like Flying Raijin,especially because Obito doesn't have his other eye.

Coming to your question,Obito materialized space-time earlier and then instantly teleported Sasuke.

Comment: I don't remember reading anywhere that Obito can prepare the Kamui for later. Can you provide a source for that?

Comment: Look up to the episode where Konan fights Obito.She dissects his technique completely.